# Tap outside to dismiss not working near the DialogFragment

Tags: android

How to make tap outside work near a DialogFragment? I've already set the elevation to zero. Is there any other shadow around it that is preventing the tap to happen? How to remove it?

Comment: Please add the method while showing DialogFragment `setCancelable(true)`

Answer (score 0):

Set `isCancellable` to `true` as follow:

```
isCancellable = true
```